# AngularJS : ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am new in AngularJs, ng-click is not working as expected. I searched on the internet , Follow the tutorial , (that was working) - but this is not working!!!

My Code:

```
<div class="row" ng:repeat="follower in myform.all_followers | partition:2">
    <ons-col class="views-row" size="50" ng-repeat="data in follower" >
        <img ng-src="http://dealsscanner.com/obaidtnc/plugmug/uploads/{{data.token}}/thumbnail/{{data.Path}}" alt="{{data.fname}}" ng-click="showDetail2(data.token)"/>
        <h3 class="title" ng-click="showDetail2('ss')">{{data.fname}}</h3>
    </ons-col>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
//Follows Controller
app.controller('FollowsController', function($scope, $http) {
    var ukey = window.localStorage.ukey;

    $scope.myform ={};
    $scope.myform.reports ="";
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var dataObject = "usertoken="+ukey;
    var responsePromise = $http.post(server_url+"follows/", dataObject,{});
    responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status,    headers, config) {
        $scope.myform.all_followers = dataFromServer;
        console.log(dataFromServer);

        //alert(dataFromServer);
        $scope.showDetail = function(index) {
            profileusertoken =  index;
            $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('profile.html'); 
        }

        function showDetail2(index) {
            alert("here");
        }

        $scope.showDetail2 = showDetail2;
    });
});
```

Niether showDetail working nor showDetail2
Please help
Thanks

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Which element did you bind your controller to? Don't forget `ng-repeat` creates its own scope.

Comment: Check if `ons-col` directive is not creating its own isolate scope. If that's the case, the `showDetail2` function will not be available. (Quick test, set the `ng-click` on the `<div>` and see if it works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rw6DZvE9EPX9Zc0tiPhx?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.16" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="FollowsController">
    <div class="row" ng:repeat="follower in myform.all_followers">
      <ons-col class="views-row" size="50" ng-repeat="data in follower">
        <img ng-src="http://dealsscanner.com/obaidtnc/plugmug/uploads/{{data.token}}/thumbnail/{{data.Path}}" alt="{{data.fname}}" ng-click="showDetail2(data.token)" />
        <h3 class="title" ng-click="showDetail2('ss')">{{data.fname}}</h3>
      </ons-col>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
//Follows Controller
app.controller('FollowsController', function($scope, $http) {
    var ukey = window.localStorage.ukey;
    //alert(dataFromServer);
    $scope.showDetail = function(index) {
        profileusertoken =  index;
        $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('profile.html'); 
    }

    function showDetail2(index) {
        alert("here");
    }

    $scope.showDetail2 = showDetail2;
    $scope.myform ={};
    $scope.myform.reports ="";
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var dataObject = "usertoken="+ukey;
    //var responsePromise = $http.post("follows/", dataObject,{});
    //responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status,    headers, config) {

    $scope.myform.all_followers = [[{fname: "blah"}, {fname: "blah"}, {fname: "blah"}, {fname: "blah"}]];
});
```

Comment: I was using ng-controller="MyController as ctrl"... and then ctrl.doSomething(). Removing the ctrl thing and using the method directly, as you did, worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Vaibhav The format you were using will only work if you assign the methods to the `this` object of your function and not `$scope` directly.

Answer (score 12):

Just add the function reference to the $scope in the controller:

for example if you want the function MyFunction to work in ng-click just add to the controller:

```
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
   $scope.MyFunction = MyFunction;
}]);
```

Answer (score 8):

It just happend to me. I solved the problem by tracing backward from the point ng-click is coded. Found out that an extra

```
</div>
```

was placed in the html to prematurely close the div block that contains the ng-click.

Removed the extra

```
</div>
```

then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

For ng-click working properly you need define your controller after angularjs script binding and use it via $scope.

Answer (score 1):

i tried using the same ng-click for two elements with same name `showDetail2('abc')`

it is working for me . can you check rest of the code which may be breaking you to move further.

[here is the sample jsfiddle i tried:](http://jsfiddle.net/dulcedilip/7jg5nyyv/26/)

Answer (score 1):

My actual component wasn't visible due to `*ngIf`, and I was clicking on another component and expecting click to work.
This can happen if you copy/paste code or work on existing code after long.