# ng-click not firing in a span element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've this simple code, when put the `ng-click` on other elements it works, but on `span` tag it is not working, I've tried to increase the size of icon just to be sure, but still not working

```
<div class="customerHeader">
      <p class='customerName'>{{customer.first_name}} {{customer.last_name}}</p>
      <span ng-click="onCustomerClick(customer)" class="delete fa fa-close"></span>
</div>
```

and here is the associated controller

```
app.controller('CustomerController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.customerName = "Ahsan";
    console.log('Customer name')
    $http.get('app/resources/customers.json').then(data => {
        // console.log('request data: ', data.data);
        customerList = data.data;
        $scope.customers = data.data.slice(0, 15);
    });
    $scope.onCustomerClick = function(clickedCustomer) {
        console.log('Customer clicked', clickedCustomer.first_name);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This exact function works on other elements on the same page and same controller?

Comment: yes, exactly, I've double checked this

Comment: If you could provide a working code example that might help.

Comment: Check this answer. Sometimes what you have is correct, but a syntax error elsewhere might be keeping things from functioning properly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801715/5781575